# Setup GMX email with SSMTP linux

Tags: linux

I setup the simplest outgoing email server possible with `ssmtp`. It is giving me the error `ssmtp: 550 Sender address is not allowed`.
Here is my configuration without comments:

```
#/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
root=hmidaniabdelilah@gmx.com 
mailhub=mail.gmx.com:587
rewriteDomain=gmx.com 
hostname=gmx.com 
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=mailexample@gmx.com 
AuthPass=password 
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

Running output:

```
~# echo "E-Mail testing SSMTP" | ssmtp -vv hmidaniabdelilah921@gmail.com
[<-] 220 gmx.net (mrgmx004) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready
[->] EHLO gmx.com
[<-] 250 STARTTLS
[->] STARTTLS
[<-] 220 OK
[->] EHLO gmx.com
[<-] 250 SIZE 69920427
[->] AUTH LOGIN
[<-] 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
[->] aG1pZGFuaWFiZGVsaWxhaEBnbXguY29t
[<-] 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
[<-] 235 Authentication succeeded
[->] MAIL FROM:<root@gmx.com>
[<-] 550 Sender address is not allowed.
> ssmtp: 550 Sender address is not allowed.
```

Comment: Your hostname is not gmx.com. Enter a valid name for that, GMX doesn't accept mail from their rootuser ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> `[->] MAIL FROM:<root@gmx.com>`

GMX rightfully rejects this: you can't send from root@gmx.com.

> `FromLineOverride=YES`

how 'bout `NO`?

Comment: I changed it to "NO", but the same problem :

`FromLineOverride=NO`